# Recursive functions with multiple arguments Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, multiplication

A really simple question: I want to implement the multiplication of 2 integers in Haskell.
What I wrote doesn't compile:

```
mult :: Int -> Int -> Int

mult x 1 = x

mult 1 y = y

mult x y = x + (mult x-1 y)
```

The problem is the last statement. I've tried writing it as:

```
mult x y = x + (mult x-1 y)
```

and also

```
mult x y = x + (mult(x-1,y))
```

The error I get is:

```
   Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Int -> Int'
    In the return type of a call of `mult'
```

I don't know why the compiler would say that `mult` returns an `Int -> Int` when it clearly returns an `Int`.

Comment: When you apply `mult` to one argument, like this `mult 5`, you get something of type `Int -> Int` because you have partially applied it to one argument. Plainly, you have `mult 5 :: Int -> Int`. This is pretty unrelated to the issue you're having now, but I thought it might be a useful side note for the future, if not for now. If it is confusing now, ignore this until later and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to put `x-1` into brackets! Like so

```
mult x y = x + (mult (x-1) y)
```

By the way, this does not compute the multiplication of x and y :-) 
Try some examples... it's a little mistake only.

Comment: haha yea just realized it.. really dumb mistake though really easy to spot :)

Answer (score 4):

In

```
mult x y = x + (mult x-1 y)
```

the expression within the parentheses parses as:

```
(mult x) - (1 y)
```

And so the compiler thinks the first argument to `(-)` is `mult x`, which is an `Int -> Int` function because just one argument (rather than two) is being passed. Instead, you want:

```
mult x y = x + mult (x-1) y
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple parser issue. The compiler is reading `mult x-1 y` as `((-) (mult x) y)` when what you mean is `mult (x-1) y`. Function application binds very tightly in Haskell, so it's sometimes better to use too many parentheses rather too few, especially while you're still learning the basics of the language.

The error occurs because the type of `(mult x)` is `Int -> Int` but the type of `y` is `Int`, and you can't subtract those two things.